# how can I get the first 2 data values using foreach in c sharp

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable

Table name:obiValues

```
ACME    
Pavillions    
Shaws    
East
```

Code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in obiValues.row)
{
    this.testContext.WriteLine(row[0].ToString());
}
```

Output like this:

```
ACME
Pavillions
```

Comment: if row is using an index, first row[0] will be the first, then row[1] will be second, is that what you are looking for?, then again, you still need to check if there is actual data in the rows before you assign them or call methods on them

Comment: A simple `for` loop is more enough for your case, where you can loop through 2 items instead of using `foreach` which will loop throughout the items

Comment: @mahlatse row[0] would be column 0 not row 0.

Comment: He doesn't specify if he wants rows or columns though @Magnus

Comment: OP, is your issue still outstanding?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the LINQ `.Take()` method:

```
foreach (DataRow row in obiValues.row.Take(2))
```

This will iterate through the first two items.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the 2 first rows, do:

```
foreach (var row in obiValues.AsEnumerable().Take(2))
{
    this.testContext.WriteLine(row[0].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch from foreach to for, as foreach iterates one item a time. In a for cycle you can easily access other elements from the data source:

```
for (int i = 0; i < obiValues.row.Count - 1; i++)
{     
 this.testContext.WriteLine(obiValues.row[i].ToString());
 this.testContext.WriteLine(obiValues.row[i + 1].ToString());
}
```